# Why can I not have instance members in a static class but I can have instance members in a static methods?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

We know that If a class is made static, all the members inside the class have to be static; there cannot be any instance members inside a static class. If we try to do that, we get a compile time error.

But if have an instance member inside a static method, I do not get a compile time error.

```
    public static class MyStaticClass
    {
        // cannot do this
        //int i;

        // can do this though.
        static void MyStaticMethod()
        {
            int j;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods and properties cannot access non-static fields and events in their containing type, and they cannot access an instance variable of any object unless it is explicitly passed in a method parameter.

```
public class MyStaticClass
{
    static int j; //static member
    int i;//instance member
    static void MyStaticMethod()
    {
        i = 0; // you can't access that
        j = 0; // you can access 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leez! I get it now, even if static classes were allowed to have had instance variables, one would not be able to access them.

Answer (score 2):

Its not instance member, its (`j`) a local variable inside a static method.

Consider following non-static class.

```
public class MyStaticClass
{
    int i; //instance member
    static void MyStaticMethod()
    {
        i = 0; // you can't access that
    }
}
```

The above class has a instance member `i`, you can't access that in a static method.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void MyStaticMethod()
{
   int j;
}
```

You have a local variable `(j)` inside your static method.

For your information from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You can define a class as static if you want to guarantee that it
>   can't be instantiated, can't derive from or serve as the base for
>   another type, and can contain only static members.
>
> Static members are initialized before the static member is accessed
>   for the first time and before the static constructor, if there is one,
>   is called.